# inserting data via SQL script

Tags: sql, database, insert, bulkinsert

I have a CSV file which consists of one column. I want to insert (not import) all the elements in the columns into the database table. I know that if I wanted to insert few elements, then I can use the below statement to insert individually.

```
INSERT INTO table(column_name )
VALUES (element1);
```

But is there a method that I can insert all the elements at once?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? All of them have some tool to import CSV files

Answer (score 0):

You can just comma separate the values like below. I sometimes use Excel to do the formatting if you have a lot of values.

INSERT INTO table
(column_name)
VALUES
(element1), (element2)

Comment: The problem is I have 2 billion of rows.So how could I do this?

Comment: I think Excel can only handle a million rows or so. What's stopping you from importing the file using SQL? You could import it into a temporary table and the just write an insert statement like

Comment: INSERT INTO table(column_name) SELECT column_name FROM temp_table